# Using EF Core and OData, how can an app sort by a property in a related entity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata, ef-core-2.2

In our AspNet Core app that uses EF Core and OData, how can I implement a grid that sorts by a property in a related entity? Here is a simplified example of a grid that contains addresses where the user could click the **State** column to sort by state:

```
public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Line1 { get; set; }
    public int StateId { get; set; }
    public State State { get; set; }
}

public class State 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class AddressRepository
{
    public IQueryable Get()
    {
        return _context.Address.Include(a => a.State);
    }
}
```

When I flatten the relationship by adding a `StateName => State.Name` property to `Address` that the context ignores, the user cannot sort on that column in the grid. What would be best would be if I could map that property to `State.Name` within the data context, but I cannot quite figure out how to do that.

On the client, we use OData to sort, page, and filter. If we try to map the grid to a non-flattened object using OData's `$expand` to bring down the `State` property, how do we display flatten it for the grid but then unflatten it for the sort?

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/tree/master/WebApiCore/ODataModelAliasingSample